# Tcl source vs Tcl package

Tags: performance, tcl

Let's say that I don't care to give the full path in each source, when would I choose tcl package over tcl source? is package require faster than source?

I know what the packages protects us from sourcing the code twice, is that a problem? I'm only sourcing functions, so I don't mind the functions to be sourced twice, but it there a performance issue with this?

Answer (score 1):

Of course there is a performance issue.
Think about what happens when you run a source command:

- The path supplied to the source command must be opened.
  The operating system checks the path for permissions, resolves symbolic links.
  This is minor for your particular case.
  This can be a major hit for some applications that check file paths over and over
  (e.g. web servers).
- The file is read in.
  Disk I/O.  Always slow.
- The file is parsed, and interpreted.
  Parsing is always slow.
  Tcl has a simple rule set, so its parsing is probably faster than some.
- Since your functions are replaced...
  The issue here is that the byte code compiler now forgets any optimizations
  that were in place and the function will run slower than usual the first time
  it is used.

Always be aware of what resources (cpu, disk, memory, network) your program is using, and try to minimize the usage.

Opinion:  You will find people that just say, "get better hardware".  These people are fools and this is the reason why most of the web is so slow.  They waste resources needlessly.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your core question:

> Is `package require` faster than `source`?

***They're not directly comparable.***

Packages are a higher-level concept than script files you can `source`, and are often *implemented* by `source`ing a file or few. There is also a caching mechanism, so that while the first time you do a `package require` it will be definitely substantially slower than `source` (as the package management subsystem needs to search through the packages you've got if it doesn't recognise the one you ask for, which actually involves using `source` on quite a few `pkgIndex.tcl` files) subsequent calls to `package require` are probably faster, as packages are not loaded in twice. Once the internal index is built (a normally once-per-interpreter cost), `package require` of a *known but not loaded* package is not much slower than directly `source`ing its implementation files. Except there's that “higher level” thing going on: the package may not be implemented by things you can `source` at all, and might instead be using `load` of a DLL. Or it could do a mix. That's the package's business: all you usually need to know is that the functionality has a name and version. That contrasts with direct `source`, where you need to know exactly where the code is (OK, easy if it is in a known fixed location or is located relative to the current script) and also that that file is exactly what you need. In general, it's better to split policy (e.g., `package require foobar 1.2.3`) from implementation (e.g., `source -encoding utf8 /usr/local/lib/tcl/packages/foobar_1.2.3/foobar.tcl`).

---

A consequence of packages being a one-time thing is that they're *not* intended for making instances of objects and object-like things (except for those that are effectively documented singletons in the API). You `package require` to get the construction commands (which might be classes) and then you use those commands to make the instances that you need when you need them.